# How to get Id of Particular input box at the same place when focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my problem,
Please check this message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRLdl.png)

Here is the code where I want id

```
var $write = $(':input').bind('focus', function() {
        //var $write = $(this).attr("id"),
        shift = false,
        capslock = false;
```

I want id of ('input') at same place. just give me some suggestion.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You already have it `$(this).attr("id")`.  How/where are you trying to use it?

Comment: but sir it is inside of function but I want at where my ('input') I got id here on focus

Comment: That means you want id of particular input field right???

Comment: i use id here $(':input').bind('focus', function() not inside the function

Comment: yes sir i want same @siva Ganesh How to do?

Comment: check it out how i get particular input box id at same place

Comment: var textBoxId = $(this).attr("id"); // get textbox id



$("#"+textBoxId).val(textBoxId ); // set textbox id inside the same textbox

is this what you want?

Comment: Hence my question: *where are you trying to use it*?  If you're trying to use it *outside* the focus event, then you can do that with `:focus`.  eg : `$(":input:focus").addClass("redborder")`  https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Comment: Or simply remove the `var `, ie:  `$write = $(this).attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var $write = $(":input").bind('focus', function() {
 var id =$(this).attr("id");
 $("#"+id).val(id);
});
```

See the jsfiddle. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/39fvuawa/1/)

Comment: we can use this here ($(':input').bind('focus', function() {
) how??

Comment: inputId is not defined

Comment: when i use this $("#"+inputId)

Comment: have you defined inputId before?

Comment: can you check if it goes same as in the jsfiddle?

Comment: var inputId = inputId;
 var $write = $("#"+inputId).bind('focus', function() {

Comment: i use it like this

Comment: Please see the updated jsfiddle, Hope it makes sence. If it help mark my answer as answer